copy from text file to other text file , but not owerwiting first 2 lines
I would like to copy the contents of a text file has another text file but do not crush the first 2 lines of the other file, or copy and add the 2 lines to the new file
Exemple:
user1.txt:
Phill
Johne
Marie
Arthuro

user2.txt:
Allow from:
Phill
Johne

Marie, Arthuro are new users from an account list, they must be copied to the authorized user file "txt2".
I tried with several solution with cat, sed, grep, but I can't:
cat user1.txt | uniq > user2.txt;

I run uniq to avoid copying duplicate names, it is good but this solution overwrites "allow from" in user2.txt

I ca not understand your question. Can you try rephrasing it with a better example input and expected output?

I think what you are asking is to go line by line on user1.txt and append each name to user2.txt if the name does not already appear in user2.txt.  Is that correct?

grep -vFxf user2.txt user1.txt >> user2.txt ?

"selbie" Yes what I'm looking for to do

this work fine :
grep -vFxf user2.txt user1.txt >> user2.txt

thank for your help
